# WebView in android studio activates the default browser on Samsung Tab S 8.4 SM-T700?

Tags: android-studio, android-webview

I am trying to build a simple app using WebView in android studio. 
It runs okay in Nexus 5 emulator. However, when I run the same app on my real Samsung Tab S 8.4 SM-T700, the tablet asks me to select a default browser (using a dialog "open with Chrome or Internet"). And my app does not display the selected webpage.

How can I force android to run my app on Samsung Tab 8.4 S M-T700?

Here is the relevant code segment:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url= "http://www.google.com";
    WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

before your call to `loadUrl`. Google does a redirect, and redirects should be handled by a `WebViewClient`. When it's not set, WebView passes the URL to the default browser. Setting an empty `WebViewClient` makes WebView to load the URL in itself.

Comment: Thank you Mr @Mikhail Naganov! It worked!
However, when I try to play YouTube video, it does not play. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: @user2013976: Glad it helped! Looks like you are missing a call to `view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Following connects to YouTube but doe not play the video:  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView v=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = v.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        v.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        v.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        v.loadUrl(YouTubeURL);
    }